# STContains always returns 0 when i query from table. But same data works when I manually create a polygon geometry object and select

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-spatial, st-geometry

I'm new to sql geometry. I've a table that stores polygon or multipolygon in a column. Below given a sample stringified row. Latitude, longitude, geom columns respectively

```
  36.846642    -119.613123            POLYGON ((-120.67037807500749 36.138281341834187, -120.5952518160816 36.488562090109014, -121.21937765946595 36.910886396539652, -121.24827237443743 37.089753161616166, -120.96510416771677 37.345632006100615, -120.98244099669967 37.400285739873993, -120.38720986828683 37.633806238723878, -120.39298881128113 37.683491451245125, -120.31208360936094 37.653680323732374, -120.34097832433243 37.725723881888193, -120.08092588958895 37.827578567556756, -119.80931556885689 37.755535009400944, -119.53770524812481 37.9045906469647, -119.26031598439843 37.725723881888193, -119.12162135253524 37.733176663766379, -119.01760037863787 37.584121026202624, -118.79800054485449 37.487234861786177, -118.6650848559856 37.154343937893792, -118.43970607920792 37.059942034103415, -118.36457982028202 36.692271461446147, -118.09874844254425 36.346959234423444, -117.98316958265826 35.867496933593358, -118.00628535463547 35.78800059355936, -120.21384157845785 35.790484854185422, -120.32364149534953 35.909729364236426, -120.67037807500749 36.138281341834187))
```

Below given raw data from the same row

```
36.846642      -119.613123            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
```

My problem is,

```
    > DECLARE @g geometry;   DECLARE @h geometry;   SET @g =
        > geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((-120.67037807500749
        > 36.138281341834187, -120.5952518160816 36.488562090109014, -121.21937765946595 36.910886396539652, -121.24827237443743 37.089753161616166, -120.96510416771677 37.345632006100615, -120.98244099669967 37.400285739873993, -120.38720986828683 37.633806238723878, -120.39298881128113 37.683491451245125, -120.31208360936094 37.653680323732374, -120.34097832433243 37.725723881888193, -120.08092588958895 37.827578567556756, -119.80931556885689 37.755535009400944, -119.53770524812481 37.9045906469647, -119.26031598439843 37.725723881888193, -119.12162135253524 37.733176663766379, -119.01760037863787 37.584121026202624, -118.79800054485449 37.487234861786177, -118.6650848559856 37.154343937893792, -118.43970607920792 37.059942034103415, -118.36457982028202 36.692271461446147, -118.09874844254425 36.346959234423444, -117.98316958265826 35.867496933593358, -118.00628535463547 35.78800059355936, -120.21384157845785 35.790484854185422, -120.32364149534953 35.909729364236426, -120.67037807500749 36.138281341834187))', 0);   
    >SET @h = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-119.61334353534343 36.84664456779879)', 0);   
>SELECT @g.STContains(@h);
```

Above code works perfectly. But, whe I try to select it from the table, it is not working. query below

```
SET @h = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-119.61334353534343 36.84664456779879)', 0);  
SELECT g.geom.STContains(@h) from mygeotable g;
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? Have run the queries you've posted on SS2012 and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm on 2012. and the above query, when i'm declaring geometry object manually, is working fine. But its not selecting row when i use table. I ran STIsValid()  and all rows are fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute this query, you should get `1` and `1`. As a comment, you probably would like to use a meaningful spatial reference system id such as WGS84 (WKID `4326`) instead of just `0` when you construct geometries. Make sure you run your spatial SQL functions against geometries that are defined using the same spatial references.

```
create table geometry_polygons(    
    shape geometry
);

DECLARE @g geometry;   
DECLARE @h geometry;   

delete from geometry_polygons

set @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((-120.67037807500749 36.138281341834187, -120.5952518160816 36.488562090109014, -121.21937765946595 36.910886396539652, -121.24827237443743 37.089753161616166, -120.96510416771677 37.345632006100615, -120.98244099669967 37.400285739873993, -120.38720986828683 37.633806238723878, -120.39298881128113 37.683491451245125, -120.31208360936094 37.653680323732374, -120.34097832433243 37.725723881888193, -120.08092588958895 37.827578567556756, -119.80931556885689 37.755535009400944, -119.53770524812481 37.9045906469647, -119.26031598439843 37.725723881888193, -119.12162135253524 37.733176663766379, -119.01760037863787 37.584121026202624, -118.79800054485449 37.487234861786177, -118.6650848559856 37.154343937893792, -118.43970607920792 37.059942034103415, -118.36457982028202 36.692271461446147, -118.09874844254425 36.346959234423444, -117.98316958265826 35.867496933593358, -118.00628535463547 35.78800059355936, -120.21384157845785 35.790484854185422, -120.32364149534953 35.909729364236426, -120.67037807500749 36.138281341834187))', 4326);
insert into geometry_polygons (shape) values (@g);

SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((-120.67037807500749 36.138281341834187, -120.5952518160816 36.488562090109014, -121.21937765946595 36.910886396539652, -121.24827237443743 37.089753161616166, -120.96510416771677 37.345632006100615, -120.98244099669967 37.400285739873993, -120.38720986828683 37.633806238723878, -120.39298881128113 37.683491451245125, -120.31208360936094 37.653680323732374, -120.34097832433243 37.725723881888193, -120.08092588958895 37.827578567556756, -119.80931556885689 37.755535009400944, -119.53770524812481 37.9045906469647, -119.26031598439843 37.725723881888193, -119.12162135253524 37.733176663766379, -119.01760037863787 37.584121026202624, -118.79800054485449 37.487234861786177, -118.6650848559856 37.154343937893792, -118.43970607920792 37.059942034103415, -118.36457982028202 36.692271461446147, -118.09874844254425 36.346959234423444, -117.98316958265826 35.867496933593358, -118.00628535463547 35.78800059355936, -120.21384157845785 35.790484854185422, -120.32364149534953 35.909729364236426, -120.67037807500749 36.138281341834187))', 4326);   
SET @h = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-119.61334353534343 36.84664456779879)', 4326);   
SELECT @g.STContains(@h);

SET @h = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-119.61334353534343 36.84664456779879)', 4326); 
SELECT g.shape.STContains(@h) from geometry_polygons g; 

drop table geometry_polygons
```

Comment: Super. I already found this issue. I found SRID by using below query.
select distinct SP_GEOMETRY.STSrid from dbo.MYTABLE. 
And applied that SRID in the object creation query instead of zero. My exact issue was using different SRID

Comment: Great, glad it worked out well.